# Is it a good idea to handle all requests and responses (server side) and all API calls (frontend side) using try-catch blocks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, mern

I have a MERN Application and I am making API calls in the frontend using *axios*.

For example:

```
 // user is an object with properties email and password
    const res = await axiosInstance.post("/admin/sign-in", {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password,
          });
```

If the API call fails (for whatever reason) I get an error, so is it a good idea to always make API calls in a try-catch block. If not, what is the recommended way of doing so? I know it is possible to check the response status, but is it an improper practice to use try-catch? The status check does not work in case the server is down.

```
    try {
      const res = await axiosInstance.post("/admin/sign-in", {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
      });
} catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

Similarly, on the backend side, should I handle all requests and responses in a try-catch block so that an accidental (or deliberate ) misplaced JSON token in the request does not cause an error that shuts down the server?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the second question is somewhat silly – why _wouldn't_ you guard against an error that would shut down the server program?

Comment: @AKX what is the best way to guard against such errors?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to throw typed errors from my handlers, and not catch them there; Either an internal system error or and API error with a message for the client.

Then I catch the error higher up in the stack, in the default error handler, sending an API message to the user, and/or logging the system message internally for internal errors, depending on the error type.  This way I can catch all errors as well, eliminating boilerplate code.

This also allows me to consolidate, and control what gets sent to the client.

Comment: Okay, thank you.